# Proof for mean and variance of a multidimensional half normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, proof, multivariate-analysis

Given a $p$-dimensional random variable $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}\left( 0, I_{p} \right)$ and a $p\times p$ dimensional diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with diagonal entries $\lambda = \left( \lambda_{1},\cdots,\lambda_{p} \right)$.

Can anybody point me to a paper or help me with the proof that:

mean: $\mathbb{E} \left(\Lambda \left| \xi \right|\right)$ =
 $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\lambda$

and $\mathbb{V}ar\left( \Lambda \left| \xi \right| \right)$ = $\left( 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right) \Lambda^{2}$.

On Wikipedia, one can find the one-dimensional results which are $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\lambda$ and  $\left( 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}\right)\lambda^{2}$, respectively.

Comment: You are asking a one-dimensional question!  Because $\Lambda$ is diagonal, your expectations and variances are computed component by component.  Therefore your last line gives the answer and there's nothing left to show.